# How to integrate React Native with WooCommerce API?

Tags: react-native, woocommerce

I have started coding in the React Native programming language to build an e-Commerce mobile app for Woo Commerce backend. I have searched alot about how to integrate React Native and Woo Commerce but couldn't find something useful. I am wondering how to perfom the following using WOO COMMERCE REST API:

- Fetch data from Woo Commerce to React Native app (Example: diplsy prodcuts).
- Post data from React Native app to Woo Commerce (Exampel: Checkout, orders, payments ... etc).

How can such integration happens and is there any useful tutorial for that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: hi Raisi, Did you find the solution? If yes, Please share the tutorial links...

Comment: any updates? Badar Al Raisi

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple library for this task. It will work with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

**[react-native-wc-api](https://github.com/IntelliJAbhishek/react-native-wc-api)**

**Install**

Using npm

```
npm install react-native-wc-api --save
```

Using Yarn

```
yarn add react-native-wc-api
```

### Setup

Setup for the new WP REST API integration (WooCommerce 2.6 or later):

```
import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-wc-api';

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v1'
});
```

Setup for the old WooCommerce legacy API:

```
import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-wc-api';

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  version: 'v3'
});
```

> For More Info [Read Here](https://github.com/IntelliJAbhishek/react-native-wc-api#readme)